# Azure APIM Users List

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

Is there any way (using REST APIs) to get the list of users  based on who have added that user in Azure APIM ?
for example: if  there is 5 users added in an apim instance , out of which 2 were added by me . Then the API should return me the records of those 2 users only.

I was trying with this API:
GET GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/users?api-version=2021-08-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/%7BserviceName%7D/users?api-version=2021-08-01)

but not sure about how to filter the response in the way I need it.

Any help will be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the [Rest APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/user/get) to get the user information based on `userid` and we can [list the users based on filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/user/list-by-service) like name, first name, last name, email, state, note, group.

but we do not have a Rest API call for fetching the users based on `created by` parameter because this information is not logged as the users can be either added automatically under users when they signed up in the APIM developer portal or created from the portal.

I would suggest raising the feature request on the [Azure APIM feedback site](https://aka.ms/apimwish) and the other users who need this similar feature can upvote it which will take it forward to the Microsoft.